# palindrome 4th grade

Tags: permutations, contest-math, palindrome

This is a 4th grade question. A palindrome is an integer number that does not change when read backwards. E.g. 123321 is a 6 digit palindrome. How many 9-digit palindromes are there that use only the digits 9 and 0?

I have created a table and typing the possible numbers, but this takes more time than needed. Kindly advise the best approach to solve this problem so that a 4th grader can understand that.

Comment: Aren't there $32$ since you can choose the first $5$ digits arbitrarily?

Comment: @Guest Arguably not since you would not consider $099999990$ a nine digit number, but rather an eight digit number.  It is however a nine-digit *string*.  As a result of wishing to avoid leading zeroes, the first digit *must* be a nine.  The following four digits will completely determine the rest of the number, for a total of sixteen.

Comment: sixteen is the correct answer. How do you get sixteen? How would you explain the logic to a 4th grader? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The digit cannot start with 0 as it becomes a 8 digit no so the first no should be 9 so the last digit.
Let the remaining 7 nos be XYZPZYX. Here P can take values of 0 or 9 so two cases for P.Similarly for X,Y,Z.So total nos are 2*2*2*2(for values of X,Y,Z,P)=16

Answer (score 2):

By [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), in questions like these we set up a sequence of questions with each having a set number of possible responses such that:

- each possible sequence of answers corresponds to exactly one possible outcome of what we are trying to count
- each outcome we are trying to count is described by exactly one possible sequence of answers
- each sequence of answers does not change the number of options for each question

As we are asking for palindrome nine-digit **integers**, we set up the following picture to help remind us how to approach the problem.

$\underline{~a~}~\underline{~b~}~\underline{~c~}~\underline{~d~}~\underline{~e~}~\underline{~d~}~\underline{~c~}~\underline{~b~}~\underline{~a~}$

We set up the following sequence of questions:

- What digit is used for the first position?  (Since it can *not* be a zero since that would make it no longer a nine-digit number it **must** be a nine) ($1$ choice available)
- What digit is used for the second location?  (It can be either a zero or a nine) ($2$ choices available)
- What digit is used for the third location?  (It can be either a zero or a nine) ($2$ choices available)
- $\vdots$
- What digit is used for the sixth location?  (It must be the same as what was used in the fourth location) ($1$ choice available)
- $\vdots$
- What digit is used for the ninth location?  (It must be the same as what was used in the first location) ($1$ choice available)

Multiplying the number of options at each step, we have a total of $1\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdots 1 = 2^4=16$ possible palindromic 9-digit integers using only digits zero and nine.

Comment: Very detailed answer, +1. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a $9$-digit number, you can't use $0$ at the first place. Therefore, the first digit must be $9$, and since the number is palindrome, the last digit must be $9$ too. Now you are limited to make $7$ digit numbers($0$ can be first too) which are symmetrical. You can choose the first $4$ digits howewer you want, these are $2*2*2*2$ options(in every digit, you can choose $0$ or $9$), and you must choose the last $3$ digits to make it a palindrome, but these choices are depending on what you chose at the first $4$ options.

Your answer is therefore $16$. Hope this is understandable for your studies.

Comment: Thanks so much for the kind clarification. You all rock!